# Stripes and Distortion in classification result when performing maximum likelihood classification in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification, image

I have trouble performing a supervised classification in ArcMap 10.3.

I created training areas and executed the "interactive supervised classification"-tool, which works totally fine and gives back the expected result. Now, since I later want to integrate the classification in model builder, I have to use the "Maximum Likelihood Classification"-tool, since the interactive tool is not available in model builder.

Therefore, I saved the training areas signature file and executed the "Maximum Likelihood Classification"-tool (Input: 4-band tif and the signature file). But the result is errorneous, it contains stripes and it is distorted as well (see below both results)...
[image: Both results:]

Maybe someone has already experienced this and has advice or solution for me. In the ArcGIS-Help it says that when executing "interactive supervised classification"-tool, it internally calls the "Maximum Likelihood Classification"-tool. So I have no idea where the problem appears.

Comment: Have you set any model-specific environment attributes, like raster extent, cell size, etc?

Comment: Hey.... After it didn't work out with the standard environment settings, I set specific environment attributes for raster extent, cell size, projection and snap raster. So, yes I did, but the result is the same...

Comment: The resulting raster is adding extra rows for some reason, an error that I've seen before with BIL format. In what format are you saving your classification result raster?

Comment: Hm, ok.... I save it in tif-format

Comment: Looks like you gave me a critical hint here.... If I drop the ".tif" ending, it works as expected, thanks!